# asp.net mvc model binding fails for <List> items in editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I've searched many posts on SO and still not sure what I did wrong here.  I have a `model` for "Order" which includes a `<list>` of "OrderItem"

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int OrderType { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
}
public class OrderItem
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public decimal RetailPrice { get; set; }
    public string ProductQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, which is strongly typed to the Order model, I am using an Editor Template to display the order items

```
@model FTG.Models.Order
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.OrderItems)
```

and the editor template seems to assign a proper name for the model binding to occur:

```
input  type="number" id="OrderItems_0__ProductQuantity" name="OrderItems[0].ProductQuantity"...
input  type="number" id="OrderItems_1__ProductQuantity" name="OrderItems[1].ProductQuantity"...
```

But my model comes back to the controller with `count=0` for the list.  The rest of the model looks fine, I just can't get the values from the list of orderitems.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your model class is missing a property for the child list. Try adding a property for the OrderItems list.

Answer (score 0):

OrderItems is a field, not a property.  You need to make it a property with a getter and setter, then in your constructor you create the empty list and assign it to the property.